# Convert Apple iCloud Notes to Google Docs

Tags: icloud, notes.app, formatting, import, google-docs

Is it possible to convert some of my Apple Notes that are currently in my iCloud, over to Google Docs?

I use about 7 iMacs a week for work but the network here at work has been odd with letting me login to iCloud. Apple's server has issues connecting.

But all I really need is my Notes to come over to Google Docs so I can view and edit them whenever I wish while on the web. I've tried copy & paste but the format gets lost. Any ideas on how to bring those over along with the text format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Notes` on your iOS device:

- **Export (Share)** the note via **email** to yourself. Then you can copy-paste it nicely from the email.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/284695/3237

Answer (score 1):

You should try using Google Keep, since Google Keep is also a Notes app, the text should not get unformatted.

Comment: I tried that 1st but Google Keep doesnt format text at all. Its unsupported.